# How do handle this mixed config in one file with python ttp parser?

Tags: python, text-parsing

I'm working on a parser for VPLS service config on Nokia SR node with python TTP parser. The following are two samples of evpn config on VPLS service. I want to focus on the **bgp** and **bgp-evpn** parts now.

```
        description "evpn-mpls-service with single-active multihoming"
        bgp
        bgp-evpn
            evi 10
            mpls
              no shutdown
              auto-bind-tunnel resolution any
        spoke-sdp 2:1 create 
        exit
```

--

```
        bgp
            route-distinguisher 63.130.124.186:50050
            route-target export target:4445:50050 import target:4445:50050
        exit
        bgp-evpn
            mpls bgp 1
                control-word
                auto-bind-tunnel
                    resolution-filter
                        ldp
                        rsvp
                        sr-isis
                        sr-te
                    exit
                    resolution filter
                exit
                no shutdown
            exit
        exit
```

The following is my **TTP** template for the second sample:

```
        <group name="bgp">
        bgp {{ _start_ }}
            route-distinguisher {{ route_distinguisher }}
            <group name="route_target**">
            route-target export target:{{ export_target}} import target:{{ import_target }}
            </group>
        exit {{ _end_ }}
        </group>

        <group name="bgp_evpn">
        bgp-evpn {{ _start_ }}
            <group name="mpls">
            mpls {{ reference | ORPHRASE }}
                <group name="auto_bind_tunnel">
                auto-bind-tunnel {{ _start_ }}
                    <group name="resolution_filters">
                    resolution-filter {{ _start_ }}
                        {{ resolution_filter | _line_ }}
                    exit {{ _end_ }}
                    </group>
                    resolution {{ resolution }}
                exit {{ _end_ }}
                </group>
                no shutdown {{ state | set("enabled") | default("disabled") }}
            exit {{ _end_ }}
            </group>
        exit {{ _end_ }}
        </group>
```

Since both config format may exist in a single config file. I need to use one template to cover both cases. Is it doable? How should I adjust my template for this?

Answer (score 0):

this template:

```
    <group name="bgp">
    bgp {{ _start_ }}
        route-distinguisher {{ route_distinguisher }}
        <group name="route_target**">
        route-target export target:{{ export_target}} import target:{{ import_target }}
        </group>
    exit {{ _end_ }}
    </group>

    <group name="bgp_evpn">
    bgp-evpn {{ _start_ }}
    
        <group name="evi">
        evi {{ reference }}
        <group name="mpls_params**">
        mpls {{ _start_ }}
          no shutdown {{ state | set("enabled") | default("disabled") }}
          auto-bind-tunnel resolution {{ resolution }}
        </group>
        </group>        
    
        <group name="mpls">
        mpls {{ reference | ORPHRASE }}
            <group name="auto_bind_tunnel">
            auto-bind-tunnel {{ _start_ }}
                <group name="resolution_filters">
                resolution-filter {{ _start_ }}
                    {{ resolution_filter | _line_ }}
                exit {{ _end_ }}
                </group>
                resolution {{ resolution }}
            exit {{ _end_ }}
            </group>
            no shutdown {{ state | set("enabled") | default("disabled") }}
        exit {{ _end_ }}
        </group>
        
    exit {{ _end_ }}
    </group>
```

Gives this output:

```
[
    {
        "bgp": {
            "route_distinguisher": "63.130.124.186:50050",
            "route_target": {
                "export_target": "4445:50050",
                "import_target": "4445:50050"
            }
        },
        "bgp_evpn": [
            {
                "evi": {
                    "mpls_params": {
                        "resolution": "any",
                        "state": "enabled"
                    },
                    "reference": "10"
                }
            },
            {
                "mpls": {
                    "auto_bind_tunnel": {
                        "resolution": "filter",
                        "resolution_filters": {
                            "resolution_filter": "ldp\nrsvp\nsr-isis\nsr-te"
                        }
                    },
                    "reference": "bgp 1",
                    "state": "enabled"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Tested above using this sandbox: https://textfsm.nornir.tech/

Not sure if this is what you after but it can parse both formats and combine them in overall results, also for sros this repo might be a useful source of examples: https://pypi.org/project/ttp-sros-parser/